# Error java.lang.NullPointerException en Android

Tags: android

Cuando inicio mi aplicación en Android, este funciona correctamente pero cuando trato de pasar esta  app a segundo plano tengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo en el MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity...
.
.
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mTcpClient.stopClient();
    mTcpClient = null;
    mTcpClient.stopClient();

    arrayList.clear();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en la clase TcpClient:

```
public class TcpClient {
.
.
public void stopClient() {

    statusWIFIX = false;
    Log.e( "DEBUG-->", "Coneccion Cerrada: "+ statusWIFIX );
    sendMessage(Constants.CLOSED_CONNECTION+": " + Modelox);                
// send message that we are closing the connection
    mRun = false;
    if (mBufferOut != null) {
        mBufferOut.flush();
        mBufferOut.close();
    }
    mMessageListener = null;
    mBufferIn = null;
    mBufferOut = null;
    mServerMessage = null;
}
```

Alguien me podria decir como corregir esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dice el titulo, hay algo nulo.

Y en el método de onPause, pones en nulo a mTcpClient antes de usar el stopClient, aunque lo usas dos veces(stopClient), solo elimina el segundo StopClient.

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mTcpClient.stopClient();
    mTcpClient = null;
    mTcpClient.stopClient();

    arrayList.clear();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

tu error es el siguiente:

```
mTcpClient.stopClient();
mTcpClient = null;
**mTcpClient.stopClient();**
```

debido a que mTcpCliente es null, cuando llamas a stopClient() este arrojara "nullPointerException" que es una exception que denota ausencia del elemento que estas intentando llamar.

saludos y buena energia.

//// AGREGANDO////
tambien noto que usas el notifydatasetchange(), te sugiero que este no lo llames en el onPause() llamalo en el onResume(), esto debido a que asumo que intentas refrescar la data que este dentro del adapter, pero la app al entrar en onPause quiere decir que la estas enviando a background, pero pues... no tiene sentido refrescar la data en este momento, es mejor llamarlo cuando vuelve a la vista :)